# timeout in telegram.bot webhook - asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

I had been developed a telegram bot using Telegram.Bot.

I tried to rework with the bot, First I created bot using BotFather and got token.

I set webhook server api address in telegram api. But when I check webhookinfo it returns this error

https://api.telegram.org/botToken/getWebhookinfo

respone:

```
"last_error_date":1585419712,"last_error_message":"Connection timed out"
```

I checked it need TLS12 to have secure connection using

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

But It's not getting updates in my server and show time out error.

I tried posting using postman and ngrok to run on my iisexpress and I'm getting data and can sending messages to bot in my localhost.

But In hosting it's not working, whats wrong with new Telegram.Bot library or telegram server?

---

**update**

I checked with postman my hosting url, post man also cant connect to that url. what can be wrong with my codes?

This is response when i'm call update receiving URL in my hosting:

```
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 10.10.34.35:443
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got problem, the certificate which we use should be valid one, not free.

For more information please study this link: 
https://core.telegram.org/bots/webhooks